# How can I create and load resource.dll for localization?

Tags: localization, resources

I am developing a function to translate the menu during runtime.
Generated a dll from below code, but I don't know how to use it.
Some resource dll file already embedded when I compile and it works well.

1. Generate *.resx file.

   ```
    using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(fullPath))
    {
        writer.AddResource("Key1", "Test1");
        writer.AddResource("Key2", "Test2");
        writer.AddResource("Key3", "Test3");
        writer.Generate();
    }
   ```
2. Generate *.resource file from *.resx.

   ```
    ProcessStartInfo info1 = new ProcessStartInfo("ResGen.exe", fullPath)
    Process.Start(info1);
   ```
3. Genrate dll from *.resource.

   ```
    ProcessStartInfo info2 = new ProcessStartInfo("al.exe", $@"/t:lib /link:{path}{resourcefileName}.resources /culture:en /out:{resourcefilepath}.resources.dll");
    Process.Start(info2);
   ```

Now, How can I load this result?